# como hacer una consulta a un div con javascript y devolver true or false

Tags: javascript

Quiero automatizar una tarea y consultar cuando hay una notificación nueva de un canal de Telegram.
La consulta se hará por Telegram Web y esa consulta tiene que arrojarme true si hay un nuevo mensaje y false si no lo hay.

```js
document.querySelector("#folders-container > div > div.chatlist-top > ul > a:nth-child(1) > div.user-caption > p.dialog-subtitle > div")

let unreadBadge = new Boolean("");
console.log(unreadBadge);
```

Comment: Y ese div como tendría que estar para ser True o False?

Comment: *esa consulta tiene que arrojarme true si hay un nuevo mensaje y false si no lo hay.* -> es lo que entiendo

Answer (score 0):

No entendí muy bien tu pregunta, pero si lo que quieres validar es si el `div` que contendrá el mensaje está vacío o no y depende a esto te retorne `true` o `false`, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
function verificarMsg1() {
  let mensaje1 = document.getElementById('mensaje1').textContent;
  return mensaje1 === "" ? false : true;
}

function verificarMsg2() {
  let mensaje2 = document.getElementById('mensaje2').textContent;
  return mensaje2 === "" ? false : true;
}

console.log(verificarMsg1());
console.log(verificarMsg2());
```

```html
<h3>Telegram:</h3>
<div id="mensaje1">mensaje nuevo.</div>
<div id="mensaje2"></div> <!-- sin mensaje -->
```